# untranslated characters and their meaning

Tags: meaning, characters, character-identification

I recently saw a movie where this appeared and unfortunately, this was the only part that wasn’t translated. Could anyone tell me what it says?

[image]

Comment: 天使都是服役的灵；奉差遣为那将要承受救恩的人效力。——路加福音 第一章二十六节。So It comes from [Gospel of Luke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Luke), possibly Chapter 1 verse 26. Maybe you can look it up in English.

Comment: A question version is like " Are not all angels ministering spirits sent to serve those who will inherit salvation" (Hebrews 1:14). Converted back to a statement will be "All angels are ministering spirits sent to serve those who will inherit salvation"

Comment: I put the image into [this Chinese OCR webpage](https://online.easyscreenocr.com/Home/ChineseOCR) and it gave the correct answer; see also [How do I self-answer “What does this say?”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not quite familiar with the Holy Bible, as far as I can tell, it says it is quoted from Luke 1:26, while the text actually says

> Are not all angels ministering spirits sent to serve those who will inherit salvation?

Of course, this is actually Hebrews 1:14, which disagrees with what is referenced.

Thanks to @user3528438, whose comment helped me find the actual quotation.